# Why i am not able to call adapter method from my activity

Tags: android

I have defined a method **removeItem** in my Adapter class and i am trying to call that method from my activity but it doesn't recognize my method when i use the dot operator with my adapter class reference. Please help me out here.

```
public class RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<EventDetails_Helper> list;
String startdate,enddate;
List<Date> dates;
MaterialCalendarView calendar_view;
AppBarLayout appbar_calendar;


RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter(List<EventDetails_Helper> list, MaterialCalendarView calendar_view, AppBarLayout appbar_calendar){

    this.list = list;
    this.calendar_view = calendar_view;
    this.appbar_calendar = appbar_calendar;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewcalendar_item, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.txtview_eventname.setText(list.get(position).name);
    holder.txtview_enddate.setText(list.get(position).target_date);

    holder.linearlayout_calendar.setTag(R.id.startdate,"2018-02-17");
    holder.linearlayout_calendar.setTag(R.id.enddate,list.get(position).target_date);


    holder.linearlayout_calendar.setOnClickListener(new CalendarLinearListener());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreItem(EventDetails_Helper item, int position) {
    list.add(position, item);
    // notify item added by position
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView txtview_eventname,txtview_enddate,txtview_startdate;
    LinearLayout linearlayout_calendar;
    public RelativeLayout viewBackground, viewForeground;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        linearlayout_calendar = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_calendar);
        txtview_eventname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtview_eventname);
        txtview_startdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtview_startdate);
        txtview_enddate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtview_enddate);

        viewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
        viewForeground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);

    }

}

private class CalendarLinearListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        appbar_calendar.setExpanded(true);
        calendar_view.clearSelection();

        startdate = (String) v.getTag(R.id.startdate);
        enddate = (String) v.getTag(R.id.enddate);

        dates = getDates(startdate,enddate);
        datemarkstyle(dates);

    }
}

private static List<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2)
{
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;

    try {
        date1 = df1 .parse(dateString1);
        date2 = df1 .parse(dateString2);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);


    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    while(!cal1.after(cal2))
    {
        dates.add(cal1.getTime());
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}

private void datemarkstyle(List<Date> dates) {

    try{

        calendar_view.setCurrentDate(dates.get(0));
        int i;
        int year,month,day;

        for(i=0;i<dates.size();i++){

            calendar_view.setDateSelected(dates.get(i),true);
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

In my Activity i am doing the following :-

```
        @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {

        if(viewHolder instanceof RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter.ViewHolder){

            String name = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).name;

            EventDetails_Helper deleteditem = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            int deleteIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            mAdapter.removeItem
        }
    }
```

But the thing is it is not allowing me to access the method **removeItem();**

Comment: can you share code where your declare your `mAdapter` inside your activity

Comment: @AbhinavGupta not necessary to make it static

Comment: `RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter mAdapter` init it like this .. instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter` **my very best guess**

Comment: @AbhinavGupta its basic java..object creation is not required for static initialization **but he is creating mAdapter**

Comment: `RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter mAdapter;` -->If u have created object of that adapter, then definitely you can use that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have declared your  `mAdapter` as a **`RecyclerView.Adapter`**
not as **`RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter`**

Change it

Use this

**`RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter mAdapter;`**

Instead of

**`RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;`**

Than you can use like this `mAdapter.removeItem(deleteIndex);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's your sintax here or in the project also but

```
mAdapter.removeItem
```

is incorrect

Should be

```
 mAdapter.removeItem(position);
```

or
`mAdapter.removeItem(deleteIndex);`

And make sure you use `RecyclerViewCalendarAdapter` instance

Comment: i know that this syntax is not correct but i did that for purpose to show you that removeItem method is not accessible. Thanks anyways. @Nilesh Rathod i had done the same way as you pointed out. Thanks